# Why is SDL not loading my images when main application is accessed via shortcut?

Tags: c++, image, sdl, shortcut

I have recently created a program using C++ and the SDL library. Originally, all the images and DLLs were in the same folder as the main application. I wanted to make the main application easier to find, so I instead moved all the images into their own folder and modified my source code to find them in the correct folder. So far, so good. The main application still remains in the same folder as the DLLs.

I created a shortcut to the main application and put that it's own folder. I changed the target to **%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /q/c start "" ""%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe %UserProfile%\Desktop\Cupcake Corner Build 2.0 (exe test)\dependecies\Cupcake Corner.exe"** in an attempt to make a universal shortcut, so that the shortcut would work for any user I send the files to.

After all said and done, I've ran into a problem. If I open the main application itself, it will load the images and work perfectly. If I try to the main application via its shortcut, the window will open correctly and display the correct title, although none of the images will load. I tried moving some files around to see if the shortcut would see them if I put the resource folder elsewhere, but so far no luck.

images here -> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Cupcake Corner Build 2.0\dependecies\resources
main app/dlls here -> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Cupcake Corner Build 2.0\dependecies\
shortcut here -> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Cupcake Corner Build 2.0\

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2010. I think it has something to do with the way I have my project directory set in project options, but I'm honestly baffled at this point. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think the problem is that your app is looking for its files under the current directory, and the current directory can be any arbitrary directory. Instead it should either look for them using a fully qualified path, which can be either hardcoded or taken from the registry (you'll first need to write it there, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when dealing with files in an application (that the application knows internally, at least), you will want to have absolute paths.

The best way to solve this is by having a (set of) function(s) that add the absolute path (found by [`GetModuleFilename(0, ...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or from some configuration for example in the registry)

std::string myfiles_root_path = FindMyFilesRootPath();

std::string MakeFullPath(const std::string &filename)
  {
      return myfiles_root_path + filename;
  }

The function `FindMyFilesRootPath()` uses one of the methods above to find the appropriate path, and `filename` is the name of a file local to your application.